Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}$
How can I calculate this limit?
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}$$
I think this limit is equal to $1$, but I don´t know how to make this.

This is a so-called indeterminate form, where both the numerator and denominator tend to zero when considered separately.  Such expressions involving two variables are sometimes going to approach limits that depend on what path the variables follow.  So the issue is first of all to discover if the limit is the same regardless of which path they follow to $(0,0)$.  Is all of this pretty well-known to you?

Substitute $x=rcosa$ and $y=rsina$

As @Curious One said, using polar coordinates will be pretty useful here. Let $x=r\cos (\theta)$ and $y=r\sin (\theta )$ for some $r>0$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. We have :
$$\underset{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}{\text{lim}} \frac{x^3 + \sin (x^2+ y^2)}{y^4 + \sin (x^2+ y^2)}=\underset{r \rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{(r\cos (\theta))^3 + \sin (r^2)}{(r\sin (\theta ))^4 + \sin (r^2)}$$
We know that $\sin (r^2) \underset{r \rightarrow 0}{\sim} r^2$ so the equality becomes :
$$\underset{r \rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{(r\cos (\theta))^3 + r^2}{(r\sin (\theta ))^4 + r^2}=\underset{r \rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{r\cos (\theta)^3 + 1}{r^2\sin (\theta )^4 + 1}=1$$

Since
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}=1\iff\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^4}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}=0,$$
So we shall prove
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}
=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^4}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}=0.$$
Those are implied by:
$$\frac{|x|^3}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}\leq\frac{|x|^3}{y^4+\frac{2}{\pi}(x^2 + y^2)}\leq\frac{\pi}{2}|x|\to0,\ (x,y)\to0;$$
$$\frac{y^4}{y^4+\sin(x^2 + y^2)}\leq\frac{\pi}{2}y^2\to0,\ (x,y)\to0.$$
Here we use the inequality:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}x<\sin x,\quad x\in(0,\pi/2).$$

I want to know why downvote, are there some mistakes in my proof? Please point out,  so I can fix them.

Looks correct to me.
